# Kivy Treeview Position Issues

Tags: python, treeview, kivy

I am trying to create a layout with 2 sections that have a label over each and a view below (`TreeView` on the left and a window showing details on the right, e.g. "click on this node and see details"). I've got the labels sized and positioned, but when I add the TreeView, instead of fitting under the label, it pushes both labels over, no matter the position.

Here's the current result:
[image]

My `main.py` file--

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel


class MainScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        bridge_view = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Clients'),
                               hide_root=False, indent_level=4,
                               pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0},
                               size_hint=(0.1, 0.5))

        clients = {'client1': 'Connection A',
                   'client2': 'Connection B'}

        for client in clients.keys():
            node = bridge_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=client))
            bridge_name = clients[client]
            bridge = bridge_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=bridge_name), node)

        self.add_widget(bridge_view)



class ConnectionApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'My Support App'
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ConnectionApp().run()
```

This is my kv file--

```
<Label>:
    font_size: 30


<MainScreen>:

    Label:
        text: "Connections"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.5
        pos_hint: {"left": 0.2, "top": 1.2}
        color: 1,0,1,1
        outline_color: 1,0,1,1


    Label:
        text: "Modules"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.5
        pos_hint: {"right": 0.2, "top": 1.2}
```

Another thing that seems strange to me was how I had to use `pos_hint` to get my label spacing to work. As I understand it, these values should be on a scale between 0-1. A [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/kivy-float-layout/) I read indicated as much--

> Pos_hint gives a hint at the position, which is measured relatively
>   between 0 and 1, where 1 is "completely" something and 0 is "not"
>   something.

Does anyone know why it took using a value greater than 1 for "top" to get these labels at the top? I'm guessing this may be a hint as to why my layout isn't showing up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TreeView under Labels

The solution is to use GridLayout as child of BoxLayout (root widget, MainScreen), Labels and TreeViews as child of GridLayout. Added an ObjectProperty, `container` to hook it up to the GridLayout widget (place holder for the TreeView widget) created in the kv file. Please to the example for details.

## Example - TreeView under Labels

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Label>:
    font_size: 30


<MainScreen>:
    container: tree_view
    orientation: 'vertical'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.1

        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            text: "Connections"
            color: 1,0,1,1
            outline_color: 1,0,1,1


        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    # blue
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            text: "Modules"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        id: tree_view
''')


class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        bridge_view = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Clients'),
                               hide_root=False, indent_level=4,
                               pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0},
                               size_hint=(0.1, 0.5))

        clients = {'client1': 'Connection A',
                   'client2': 'Connection B'}

        for client in clients.keys():
            node = bridge_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=client))
            bridge_name = clients[client]
            bridge = bridge_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=bridge_name), node)

        self.container.add_widget(bridge_view)


class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

## Output - TreeView under Labels

[image: Img01 - TreeView under Labels]

## pos_hint: {'top': 1}

The reason you have to use a value greater than 1 for `top` because the Label widget's height is 0.5 (`size_hint: 0.1, 0.5`). The solution to use `pos_hint: {'top': 1}` is to reduce `size_hint_y` as shown in the snippets.

In my example, Label's canvas color were added for visualization/demonstration.

## Snippets

```
Label:
    ...
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
```

## Example - pos_hint

### kv file

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Label>:
    font_size: 30


<MainScreen>:

    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        text: "Connections"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"left": 0.2, "top": 1}
        color: 1,0,1,1
        outline_color: 1,0,1,1


    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    # blue
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        text: "Modules"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"right": 0.2, "top": 1}
```

## Output - pos_hint

[image: Img01 - pos_hint]

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps visualize where the label is. What I'm confused about is why the TreeView seems to need the entire column. If I increase the width size hint on the labels, it pushes the TreeView more to the right. Is there no way to fit a TreeView under a label?

Comment: Please refer to updated post showing TreeView under Labels.

Comment: That's definitely it. Thanks so much! I'm not 100% sure how the object property comes into play (I've been reading some of the Kivy book and docs online but not entirely clear yet), but I'll check out some YouTube videos and see if I can find some good resources, I guess.

Comment: The ObjectProperty, `container` is used to hook it up to the GridLayout widget (place holder for the TreeView widget) created in the kv file.